# RPCs on Websockets with Scala and JS (like SignalR)

Tags: websocket, real-time, rpc, collaboration

I want to implement an application based on Scala and Play! 2.1 where all data transport is handled through websockets in real-time. Since the application supports collaboration of several users, I want to be able to call methods on a) the server, b) one client, c) all clients.

For example, let's say there are Users Bob, Jane and Carl.
Carl creates a "note" which is sent through the socket and then, if successfully stored, added to the DOM through basic Javascript (let's say `addNote(note)`) *on all clients*.

A sample call could look like this:

```
// sends message type createCard to server, takes <form id="card"> as data and receives a JSON object as response
mysocket.send("createCard", $('#card').serialize(), { success: function(data) {
    var card = data.card  
    mysocket.allClients().addCard(card); // appends <div id="card"> to DOM
});
```

Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 0):

See [SignalJ](http://signalj.io) - a port of SignalR ideas to PlayFramework and Akka.